# Does {$(2,-4,1),(0,3,-1),(6,0,-1)$} form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does {$(2,-4,1),(0,3,-1),(6,0,-1)$} form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$?

My attempt: I've proved that they are linearly independent.

I'm trying to show that any arbitrary element $(a,b,c)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the given vectors.

Let $(a,b,c)=\alpha_1(2,-4,1)+ \alpha_2(0,3,-1)+\alpha_3(6,0,-1)$

I'm trying to find the $\alpha_i$'s in terms of a,b,c. I'm using methods of elimination and substitution. But no matter how I do it, the $\alpha_i$'s are getting cancelled, leaving me with no value for them.

Is there any other way to find these values, or any other method to prove the spanning part?

Comment: That means the given vectors may not be independent. Double check your proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There indeed is another method to show linear independence.

If the determinant of the matrix formed by the $3$ vectors is non zero then the vectors are linearly independent.

Also, $3$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ must form a basis- that is, they will be a spanning set as well.

EDIT: Calculating the determinant gives $0$- so the vectors ARE NOT linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I make some mistake in the linear independence part using elimination. I'll use the determinant method now. But is it sufficient to prove that a set of vectors is linearly independent to prove it's a basis? By definition it has to be a spanning set too, shouldn't I prove that as well?

Comment: @Diya: A basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$ has $n$ vectors. If you already have $n$ linearly independent vectors then they must form a basis- remember that any set of linearly independent vectors can be extended to a basis..

Comment: Any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis, but any linearly independent set isn't a basis, only the maximal linearly independent set is, isn't it?

Comment: @Diya: yes: But a maximal linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ has cardinality $n$. So if you get $n$ linearly ind. vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ then its automatically a basis.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already found that the three vectors are linearly independent, then you have already found that they are a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. (I.e., three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ must span $\mathbb R^3$).

We can generalize:

> Any $n$ linearly independent vectors span $\mathbb R^n$.

But back up and check your work on linear independence: the vectors are, in fact, linearly *dependent*:  $$(6, 0, -1)^T - 3(2, -4, 1)^T = 4(0, 3, -1)^T$$ and hence, cannot span all of $\mathbb R^3$.